# Get info of specific user with soundcloud API ios

Tags: ios, soundcloud

In the API Reference of Soundcloud I found that to get the user info I have to do that:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/iduser.json
/users/{id}
```

I tried with:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/236170/tracks.json
```

To get the tracks of the user, and it worked. I don't understand why doesn't works that:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/236170.json
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would be nice to know what you mean with “doesn't work”, but could it be you're just forgetting to add your `client_id` parameter?

Comment: This is the client_id: 236170. I tried to do the request with the client_id parameter. When I said that doesn't works, I wanted refers that the Request doesn't get any info. Sorry I updated my question, I put "with" instead of "why"

Comment: That's not the client_id, that's a user id. You have to register your application at [soundcloud.com/you/apps](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps) to receive a client_id.

Comment: I do the requests without adding my cliend_id because I'm always logged into my account of Soundcloud. I only use my client_id to streaming the audio of the songs with my player. I confused the client_id with the user_id in your answer. I tried as well adding my client_id before I post the question and I got the same result. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Maybe I add wrongly my client id. I tried adding:  ".?client_id=myclientid" & "&client_id=myclientid"

Comment: Now I'm getting the user_id of the user that I want to manage getting first his tracks, and from this request getting his user_id. But I would like get the user_id easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this: 

SCAccount *account = [SCSoundCloud account];

    if (account) {

        SCRequestResponseHandler handler1;
        handler1 = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                                          options:0
                                          error:&jsonError];
            if (!jsonError && [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);
            }
        };
        [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                    onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/me.json"]
                usingParameters:nil
                   withAccount:account
          sendingProgressHandler:nil
                responseHandler:handler1];
    } else
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this link returns my user, not a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.json` from your request:

`HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/users/236170?client_id={CLIENT_ID}`

Response:

```
{
  "id": 236170,
  "kind": "user",
  "permalink": "far-too-loud",
  "username": "Far Too Loud",
  "last_modified": "2017/02/06 20:30:18 +0000",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/236170",
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/far-too-loud",
  "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000117553632-7ywdqa-large.jpg",
  "country": null,
  "first_name": "Oliver",
  "last_name": "Cash",
  "full_name": "Oliver Cash",
  "description": "Far Too Loud is all about hi-tech, dancefloor-destroying music that makes people throw their hands in the air and go crazy. Think high-energy, aggressive funk with big basslines and crazy edits and you’ll know the sound. \n\nFormed by Oli Cash and Dom Smart back in 2005, their sound quickly won fans and only two years later picked up 'Best Single' at the Breakspoll Awards.  Later that year the FTL anthem 'Play It Loud', which saw a move from breakbeat to dirty electro-house, received a massive response and remains a crowd-pleaser to this day. 2009 saw the duo split with Dom forming techno moniker Neurodriver and Oli continuing with FTL, producing a string of electro chart-smashers including 'Bring Back Boogie' and 'Megaloud'.\n\nThe bass-fueled releases of 2012’s ‘Firestorm’ EP and the follow-up 'Faster Than Light' EP received high praise from all over the bass music scene, bursting with the now familiar big production and energy. Cementing FTL’s place in the bass music scene, these paved the way for more recent releases on heavyweight labels including OWSLA, Never Say Die, Disciple, and Monstercat, and remixes for bass-lords Zomboy, Snails and Pegboard Nerds.\n\nWell experienced in delivering unique sets packed with energy, whether it’s 200 people in a sweaty underground club or 20,000 at an outdoor festival, you can be sure it’s going to go off when FTL is in control!",
  "city": "Brighton",
  "discogs_name": null,
  "myspace_name": null,
  "website": "http://fartooloud.com",
  "website_title": "Website",
  "track_count": 71,
  "playlist_count": 15,
  "online": false,
  "plan": "Pro Plus",
  "public_favorites_count": 2878,
  "followers_count": 118855,
  "followings_count": 1323,
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "product": {
        "id": "creator-pro-unlimited",
        "name": "Pro Unlimited"
      }
    }
  ],
  "likes_count": 0,
  "reposts_count": 76,
  "comments_count": 87
}
```